# Task Scheduler ScheduledDefrag, incrementally?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-task-scheduler, defragment

`\Microsoft\Windows\Defrag\ScheduledDefrag`
in task scheduler, does this actually defrag 'incrementally', maybe with  a fixed size at a time, or can it continually defragment a whole harddrive, while being disturbed now and then (making input keyboard/mouse, cancelling the process)

Specifically, would it matter if you turned it off for external harddrives only? (Large file storage)

I'm asking because it seems counter-productive to start on every idle, if it needs 8-24 hrs to finish and the computer is disturbed every 0-8 hrs at most. It just seems like a waste, or not very well thought out that it runs everytime the computer is idle, if the probability of it finishing is very low.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Actions on the task, it has the following flags set (at least on my default task)

- `-c` which performs the operation on all drives
- `-h` which runs the operation at normal priority (default is low)
- `-o` which performs the proper operation for each media type

I believe what is meant by "proper operation" is that an SSD won't be defragmented.

If you want to tweak what the scheduled task is doing, for instance to limit it to certain volumes

1. From a command prompt run `defrag /?` and review the available options
2. Edit the scheduled task, and change the Actions to include the flags you want to pass in. Note `/` is set as `-` in the scheduled task.

The answer to your first question is a bit of an unknown, as there's no threshold set on the %age to defragment from/to.

Your question about "being disturbed". This relates to the Conditions tab on the scheduled task. Note the `Stop if the computer ceases to be idle` flag.

Comment: Alright this clarifies some of the task scheduler perspective, but what I'm really eager to know is if it can actually finish any defragmentation without running for a fixed block completion like say 30mins or 1 hour before one chunk can be marked at defragmented.

Comment: That really depends on how fragmented the drive is.

Comment: Thats what I fear also. So this would mean that most of the time it's just running, but expecting to run for 12-24 hours, its a waste if your computer is interrupted every 2-6 hours and it never finishes, but starts over on every idle.

Comment: @dezza It will defrag as it runs. The fragmented space on the disk partitions will not go back to the original fragmented state if the process is killed unless you are doing some sort of full disk image restore or something like that. If it defrags space, that space is defragged regardless if the rest of the job completes or not.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Right, I'm just wondering how small each of its running cycles is, if it depends whether its big files or not, but since the default allocation size isn't that big on NTFS in general I guess you're right, that it can slowly chip away :)

Comment: @dza if my answer was helpful, please mark it as such.

Comment: The overall Windows task scheduling aspect, timing and configuration is not the question. The question is about if short intervals of defragmentation can finish any defragmentation. I gave you an upvote for effort.